# How do I differentiate a spinor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, fermions, variational-calculus, grassmann-numbers

I was trying to derive the Euler-Lagrange equation for a lagrangian and this isn't right.

\begin{align}\frac{\partial \epsilon ^{\dot{a}\dot{b}} \psi^\dagger _\dot{a}  \psi^\dagger _\dot{b}}{\partial \psi^\dagger _\dot{c}} &= \epsilon ^{\dot{a}\dot{b}} \frac{\partial \psi^\dagger _\dot{a} }{\partial \psi^\dagger _\dot{c}}\psi^\dagger _\dot{b} + \epsilon ^{\dot{a}\dot{b}} \psi^\dagger _\dot{a} \frac{\partial \psi^\dagger _\dot{b}}{\partial \psi^\dagger _\dot{c}} \\
&= \epsilon ^{\dot{a}\dot{b}} \delta_\dot{a}^\dot{c}\psi^\dagger _\dot{b} + \epsilon ^{\dot{a}\dot{b}} \psi^\dagger _\dot{a} \delta_\dot{b}^\dot{c}=\epsilon ^{\dot{c}\dot{b}} \psi^\dagger _\dot{b} + \epsilon ^{\dot{a}\dot{c}} \psi^\dagger _\dot{a}\\
&=\epsilon ^{\dot{c}\dot{b}} \psi^\dagger _\dot{b} - \epsilon ^{\dot{c}\dot{a}} \psi^\dagger _\dot{a}\\
&=
0 \end{align}

The result should be $2\psi^{\dagger\dot{c}}$

The spinor notation is from Srednicki: http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/qft.html
section 34 and 35

Comment: You have a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded algebra and spinors have parity 1. You must work consistently either with left or right derivatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an [antiderivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra)#Graded_derivations). Leibnitz rule is
$$
d (ab) = (da)b+(-1)^p a (db)
$$ where $p$ is the fermion parity of $a$.

In this case the derivative wrt $\psi$  is essentially an [interior product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product).

Comment: @Axoned2UrWorldLine  I added another link to my answer.

Comment: What about equation equation 36.25 here https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf  ? He's using the normal product rule it seems..

Comment: The 36.25  derivatives are with respect to a commuting parameter such as $x$ or $t$. The earlier one was respect to an anticommuting parameter $\psi_a$.  It is only the latter that correspond to the interior contraction $ i_{\psi_a} $